# Can anyone tell why this animation doesn't work?

Tags: jquery

I cannot make `display: block` to work on `span`.

```
$(".wishlistbtn, .compareboxbtn").hover(
    function() { $(this).children(".helppopup").show(); },
    function() { $(this).children(".helppopup").hide(); }
);
```

With mark-up:

```
<ul>
    <li class="wishlistbtn"><a href="#">Wishlist <span class="helppopup">Add to my Wishlist<img src="images/helppopup-arrow.png" alt=""></span></a></li>
    <li class="compareboxbtn"><a href="#">Compare <span class="helppopup">Add to compare box<img src="images/helppopup-arrow.png" alt=""></span></a></li>
    <li class="getquotebtn"><a href="#">Get Quote</a></li>
</ul>
```

It simply doesn't work, but the same technique works elsewhere.

Comment: Please describe the expected/actual behaviour. Simply stating `it doesn't work` will get you little help.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I thought I had jsfiddle link... http://jsfiddle.net/Tx7m6/

Comment: Nope, but please don't rely on a fiddle. Your question should include as much relevent detail as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `find` instead of `children`, as the `.hellpopup` element isn't a direct child :

```
$(".wishlistbtn, .compareboxbtn").hover(
    function() { $(this).find(".helppopup").show(); },
    function() { $(this).find(".helppopup").hide(); }
);
```

[(ugly) Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/8vLqq/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".wishlistbtn, .compareboxbtn").hover(
// the .helpopup's are grandchildrean, not children of 'this'
    function() { $(this).find(".helppopup").show(); },
    function() { $(this).find(".helppopup").hide(); }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're running the function in $(document).ready(); after the dom has loaded.